# I have no success to create my custom jQuery Validation Rule

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jquery-validate

I'd like to create my own validation rule for a jqGrid table, but my code does not work. Why?

This is the HTML:

```
<form id="frmTCstepCategorie">
    <fieldset class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
        <legend class="ui-widget">
            Categorie
        </legend>
        <table id="tableCategories" name="tableCategories">
            <tr>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div style="margin-top: 10px" class="categoriesNav">
            <input type="button" id="btnAddCategory" value="Aggiungi"/>
            <input type="button" id="btnDelCategory" value="Rimuovi"/>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

This is the JavaScript code:

```
$.validator.addMethod("categories", function(value, element) {
    console.log("Checking...");
    return true;
}, "* Required.");

$("#frmTCstepCategorie").validate({
    rules : {
        "tableCategories" : {
            categories : true
        }
    }
});

if ($("#frmTCstepCategorie").valid()) {
    console.log("Checked!");
}
```

**UPDATE**

@Sparky told me the right thing:

> Using the jQuery Validate plugin, you can only validate `<input>`, `<select>`, `<textarea>` elements.
>
> Programmatically, you could copy the data into a hidden input and validate that element instead. You would need to set the `ignore` option to [] in order to validate hidden elements, and maybe the `errorPlacement` option to put the messages where you need them.

I tried to do that, but with no success.

If I add an hidden `<input>`:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenCategories" name="hiddenCategories" />
```

and I modify the ignore parameter:

```
$("#frmTCstepCategorie").validate({
    rules : {
        "hiddenCategories" : {
            categories : true,
            ignore: []
        }
    }
});
```

It does not work.

If I change `hidden` to `text`:

```
<input type="text" id="hiddenCategories" name="hiddenCategories" />
```

It works

Where is the mistake?

Comment: sorry, but you posted no code which shows how you use jqGrid. [editrules](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editrules) is the way in jqGrid to implement validation.

Comment: Ok, but I'd like no use a validation mixed mode using different method.
Is it not possible to use jQuery Validation Plugin to validate a generic object?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't follow you. How looks jqGrid which you use? Which editing mode you use? Which validations of which columns you need to add? What you mean under the "validation mixed mode"?

Comment: Sorry, are missing some information.
I'm developing a kind of guided creation (like an installer).
There are two types of validation: the first is a validation of the contents that happens in realtime or when I'm moving between the fields, the second happens when I click the "next" button and (generally) is a required fields check.

Comment: In the case of the jqGrid, I already validated the contents into the grid using the jqGrid features, but when I click "next" button I'd like check that the jqGrid is not empty.
To do that I'd like use the same "method" that I use for the other fields that is "jQuery Validation Plugin".
Is it possilbe validate a generic jQuery-UI Plugin using a custom validation with "jQuery Validation Plugin"?

Comment: Of cause one can use plugins in jqGrid. The plugins works typically with common `<input>` elements. So you can initialize the plugin on the specified `<input>` editing elements. You should understand that you should describe the problem more detailed is you do in the current text of your question. jqGrid have 3 editing modes: cell editing, inline editing (in many variations), form editing. You wrote about some problems with `click "next" button`. What you mean exactly? I ask some questions in my previous comment, but you don't answered there. You should include more details in your question.

Comment: It's important to use the proper tags so that people can find your question.  The jQuery Validation Engine and the jQuery Validate plugin are not the same thing.  Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd like to create my own validation rule for a jqGrid table, but my code does not work. Why?

In your code, you are trying to assign the validation rule to a `<table>` element.

Using the jQuery Validate plugin, you can only validate `<input>`, `<select>`, `<textarea>` elements.  No matter what rules you use, standard or custom, these are the only elements that will work and **there is no workaround** that would allow you to validate `<table>` or `<td>` elements.

Programmatically, you could copy the data into a hidden `input` and validate that element instead.  You would need to set [the `ignore` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#ignore) to `[]` in order to validate hidden elements, and maybe [the `errorPlacement` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorplacement) to put the messages where you need them.

---

EDIT:

```
$("#frmTCstepCategorie").validate({
    ignore: [],   // <- ignore is an OPTION, not a rule
    rules : {
        "hiddenCategories" : {
            categories : true
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This is exactly the idea that I have had.
But I have no success to do it.

If I add an hidden `<input>`:

`<input type="hidden" id="hiddenCategories" name="hiddenCategories" />`

and I modify the `ignore` parameter:

    `$("#frmTCstepCategorie").validate({
        rules : {
            "hiddenCategories" : {
                categories : true,
                ignore: []
            }
        }
    });`

It does not work.

If I change `hidden` to `text`:

`<input type="text" id="hiddenCategories" name="hiddenCategories" />`

It works

Comment: @vittochan, your mistake is that `ignore` is **not** a rule.   It's an `option`.  Please [see the docs I've linked to](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#ignore) in my answer.  In other words, `ignore` is a ***sibling*** of the entire `rules` option; it only goes inside of `.validate()`, not inside of `rules` option.